# How can the following logarithm equation be proven?

Tags: logarithms

```
log(a,x)=log(b,x)/log(b,a)
```

a is the base of the logarithm which should be calculated, x is the number of which logarithm should be calculated and b is another base of logarithm meaning that the base of logarithm in divident and divisor should be equal.

Comment: The equality is true if and only if it is true when you multiply through by $\log_b(a)$ and exponentiate to base $b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr Burt taught me many years ago: "just give everything a name and it will all fall out". Write:
$$u=\log_b x$$
$$v=\log_b a$$
Then
$$b^u = x$$
$$b^v = a$$
$$(b^v)^{\frac{u}{v}} = a^{\frac{u}{v}}$$
$$b^u = a^{\frac{u}{v}}$$
$$x = a^{\frac{u}{v}}$$
$$\log_a x=\frac{u}{v}$$
as required